# Relatively compact subspace exercise.

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to solve this exercise:

Consider:
$$
K_p= \{ f\in C^1([0,1]): |f(1)|\leq M_1\quad \int_0^1|f'(t)|^p dt\leq M_2 \}
$$
and prove that this space is relatively compact in $(C^0([0,1]),||\cdot||_\infty)$. $M_1, M_2 >0$ and $p>1$. Furthermore explain why $K_p$ can't be compact.

This exercise is connected with Ascoli-Arzelà's theorem.  I  thought to consider $\{f_n\}\subset K_p$ so I have a sequence that $||f_n||_\infty<M$. Then I prove that $f_n$ are equicontinue so I can find a subsequence such that converges to a $f\in C^0([0,1])$ applying Ascoli-Arzelà's theorem. Could it be acceptable?

Comment: you've left out p, which i believe goes here:$\int_0^1|f'(t)|^pdt$

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed an outline of proof, but each affirmation has to be justified. Notice that for any $x,y\in [0,1]$ and $f\in K_p$, using the fundamental theorem of calculus and Hölder's inequality, 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant \int_x^y|f(t)|\mathrm dt\leqslant M_2^{1/p}\cdot |x-y|^{\frac{p-1}p},$$
from which equi-continuity follows.

Now it depends which version of Arzelà-Ascoli you have at your disposal. If it's the version where the family is equi-bounded at one point you are done. If it's the version where we require the family to be uniformly bounded then use the displayed equation with $y=1$.

Comment: Perfect! So my idea was acceptable! Thanks! And what about the second part? What would you do?

Comment: You have to prove that the set is not closed: find a sequence $(f_n)$ with $f_n\in K_p$ for each $n$, $f_n\to f$ uniformly but $f$ is not $C^1$.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the help! I'll try to do this.